# Easy port forwarding Linux software that does not require root

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, network-administration

I am looking for a small standalone program that listens to a port and redirects everything to another port.

Unlike iptables it should not need require root (except if you want to listen to a privileged port)

Requirements:

- Simple command-line syntax like `tinyredirect 9211 8080`
- Press CTRL-C and the redirection stops
- Runs on Linux, Java OK
- Free
- Open source
- Relatively maintained

Bonus for Ubuntu/RedHat packages.
UDP not required.

Answer (score 4):

[socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) is a simple userland program that can redirect ports:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080,fork TCP4:localhost:9211
```

- Press CTRL-C and it stops.
- Runs on Linux, packages for Ubuntu/RedHat
- Free, GNU-GPLv2
- Updated in 2014

*If you want to listen to a privileged port, you need to prefix the command by `sudo`.*

Comment: Isn't there a limitation in ports? I mean, you couldn't e.g. forward port 80 to port 90 without root IMHO.

Comment: If you want to listen to a privileged port, you need `sudo`, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Yes, that was exactly what I meant (a mental blackout prevented the term "privileged port" to come up for me blind man, should have seen it mentioned in the question itself ;)